# How to scroll to tableViewHeader programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with `tableView.tableHeaderView` so I want to `scroll` to this `view` (top).

I am scrolling with `tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)`, but this scroll only to the first row.

How can I scroll to `tableHeaderView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, move to first row in section

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
```

After simply set the `tableView's` `contentOffset` to `CGPoint.zero` in the `UIView` *animation block*, i.e.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    tableView.contentOffset = .zero
}) { (completed) in
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I tested this code and couldn't scroll to the top, it didn't even scroll to the top of the section.

Comment: when a click in a specific cell: didSelectRowAt

Comment: Are you reloading or doing anything else there?

Comment: Yes! I reload the items.

Comment: I could perform first scroll to first row and after performing your code

Answer (score 1):

Found this little extension that helps a lot!

```
public extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
        let desiredOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -contentInset.top)
        setContentOffset(desiredOffset, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this code and couldn't scroll to the top, it didn't even scroll to the top of the section.